# Flattening the values (not formulae) of a summary sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I work at a company that owns a lot of film gear that they bring on freelance shoots. I'm trying to create a simple, streamlined way for them to notate what's brought on each shoot so that they don't have to write up a new word doc every time they go on a shoot.

To do this, I made several different sheets of packages with gear they often bring, but left the option of checkmarking each item. These checkmarked items then appear on a master sheet, using variations of formula: `=if('A CAM'!A1,'A CAM'!B1,"")`

I'd like to get rid of the white space if something isn't checkmarked. I tried to flatten the column with each of these formulae, but could not, since each cell has a formula in it. Is there a way to mirror the value of the cell into a different column, then flatten that? Or another way to accomplish what I'm attempting to do?

Here's the sheet for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w946zqoUgvnKMKjXcpzaCGm-BgH_5X3SxwmKoKkuSEM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chain of formulas of the form `=if('A CAM'!A1,'A CAM'!B1,"")` try a single formula using `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER('A CAM'!B1:B100,'A CAM'!A1:A100)
```